# Do not want to have close button on my dialog

Tags: qt

is it possible to remove close button from QDialog?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I assume it's because googling "QDialog no close button" yields all the info you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [window](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html) [flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum).
For example:

```
QDialog d(0, Qt::CustomizeWindowHint|Qt::WindowTitleHint);
d.exec();
```

Comment: #aske thanks, I knew it had something to do with window flags but I couldn't get it right. Thanks.

Comment: That solution doesn't work with Qt 5.9 running on ubuntu 16.04 LTS/Unity.  Setting those hints to a QDialog just shows the dialog's widgets floating in an invisible dialog box.